# c++ access same elements in more than one way

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

My `Item` class looks like the following:

```
class Item {
    int unique_key;
    long property;
};
```

I have a number or items and I need to access them in constant O(1) time both by `unique_key` (different for every item) and `property` (more items can have the same property).

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
std::map<int, Item*> my_map1;
std::multimap<long, Item*> my_map2;
```

but I wonder if there are other better solutions that use less memory and avoid to keep maps synchronized.

Comment: What is the problem with this solution you pointed?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I would know if there are other built-in structures / patterns to deal with this kind of problem

Comment: Depending on your `unique_key` values, you may want to use a `std::vector` or `std::array` or array.  Arrays have O(1) access.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos well, one problem appears to be that it doesn't fulfil the contant access time requirement. `unordered_map` and `unordered_multimap` would resolve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to access them in constant O(1) time

Neither `std::map` nor `std::multi_map` have constant time access of elements, both are O(lg N). If you need constant access, you'll have to use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) and [`std::unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap), both containers introduced in C++11.

If you don't have access to a C++11 compiler, then there's no dictionary/hashtable container that is constant time access.

However, if the `unique_key`s are generated in such a way such that they are 0...N, and the `property`s are also 0...M, for some N, M, then you could simply have:

```
std::vector<Item*> my_map1;
std::vector<std::vector<Item*>> my_map2;
```

If you have a dense collection of IDs, that will have constant access and be the most efficient solution. But if the collection of IDs is sparse (e.g. maybe you have ids 0, 500, and 10 million), then this solution is terrible.

Comment: well, I already use unordered_map for the reasons you pointed out :) And yes, key and property are not from 0 to n but purely "random" for the purpose of my question